# How can I implement a handler in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, datatables, bundle, handler

According to the Datatable Symfony bundle documentation, I need to implement a handler.

*You have to create a handler for each DataTable instance. A handler must implements the DataTableHandlerInterface interface. The only function this interface contains is handle :*

```
  /**
   * Handles specified DataTable request.
   *
   * @param DataTableQuery $request
   *
   * @throws DataTableException
   * @return DataTableResults
   */
  public function handle(DataTableQuery $request): DataTableResults;
```

What I need to know is, where exactly do I have to put this code? In what folder and on what page?

Comment: If you followed the documentation you see they put their handlers in: AppBundle\DataTables\UsersDataTable and register it as a service: https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle/wiki#step-2-register-the-handler

Comment: @Jeroen I do not have an AppBundle Folder. Do I have to add this in my root?

Comment: Is it `UsersDataTable.php` or `UsersDataTable.yaml` ?

Comment: I think I have to create an "AppBundle" Folder in "src", is this right?

Comment: @Jarla if you have no AppBundle folder you don't have to create one. The usual case is that such a folder exists but we don't know your folder structure. Where does your code normally gets in? Which folder?

Comment: this is php code so you have to put it in a php file. and you have to replace `AppBundle` with the name of your bundle. if you don't use bundles (like in symfony 4) you have to put `DataTables` folder next to `Controller` (usually in `src`)

Comment: I created now this file `src/Controller/DataTableController.php` Would this work?

Comment: Like @JimPanse said you don't have to create one, just create a folder called "DataTables" next to your Controller and Entity folders.

Comment: That would work but if we are still talking about your handler file it would be better to name it "UsersDataTable" and put it in the folder "DataTables" because this is noot a controller.

Comment: @Jeroen Ok, so my file would be this then `src/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php`, is this what you mean?

Comment: @Jarla Yes! And you also need a controller action like explained under:
 "UserAction" in https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle/wiki#step-3-invoke-the-handler that calls the handler

Comment: Ok, thank you. I do not know why they don't explain where the code is going. For example this code `services:
    AppBundle\DataTables\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/DataTables'
        autowire: true
        public: false
        tags: [ datatable ]` On what page is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the handler file in 
`src/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php` for Symfony 4 projects.

In this file you will implement the request handler (https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle/wiki#step-1-implement-request-handler) Don't forget to register it as a service:
https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle/wiki#step-2-register-the-handler

**UsersDataTable.php**

```
// src/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php
class UsersDataTable implements DataTableHandlerInterface
{
    ///
}
```

You register services in **services.yaml**

```
#config/services.yaml

services:
   datatable.users:
       class: App\DataTables\UsersDataTable
       tags: [{ name: datatable, id: users }]
       arguments: [ '@doctrine' ]
```

After this you can invoke the handler from a controller action
https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle/wiki#step-3-invoke-the-handler

**SomeController.php**

```
// App\Controller\SomeController.php

public function usersAction(Request $request, DataTablesInterface $datatables): JsonResponse
{
   //
}
```

If you follow the instructions under: https://github.com/webinarium/DataTablesBundle/wiki#handlers-service-autoloading all your handlers will be autoloaded.

Comment: Thank you, this is much better explained than the documentation

Comment: why do your write `AppBundle\DataTables\UsersDataTable`  if the path is actually `src/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php`

Comment: My bad (copy-paste), edited my answer. Make sure you write the namespace of your class.